# I want to retrieve data from firestore using streambuilder but it returns an emplty list

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

This is when I try to prind the snapshot.data on the console

Image of the console display:
[image: Image of the console display]

In the firebase console I have a collection tree like this
collection('chat_room')>>document(chatRoomId)>>collection('message').

Here is a screenshot of it:

[image: Image of the firebase console]

Find the code where I display data using streambuilder  the data:

```
Widget _buildMessageList() {
  return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
    stream: _chatService.getMessages(
        _firebaseAuth.currentUser!.uid, widget.receiverUserID),
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasError) {
        return Text('Error ${snapshot.error.toString()}');
      }
      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting ||
          !snapshot.hasData) {
        return const Text('Loading');
      }
      if (snapshot.hasData) {
        final List<DocumentSnapshot> documents = snapshot.data!.docs;
        print(documents.toString());
        return ListView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          children: [
            Text(documents.toString()),
          ],
        );
      }
      return Container(
        color: Colors.amber,
      );
    },
  );
}
```

And here the storage service where I get the data from firestore

```
//GET MESSAGES
Stream<QuerySnapshot> getMessages(String userId, String otherUserId) {
  //construct chat room id from user ids (sorted to ensure it matches the id used when sending mesages)

  List<String> ids = [userId, otherUserId];
  ids.sort();
  String chatRoomId = ids.join('_');
  return _fireStore
      .collection('chat_rooms')
      .doc(chatRoomId)
      .collection('messages')
      .orderBy('timestamp', descending: false)
      .snapshots();
}
```

Comment: The code for loading from Firestore looks fine at first glance, so you might want to: 1) print `_firebaseAuth.currentUser!.uid` and check if it matches the `B4Dy...` collection name in your screenshot

Comment: When I print the _firebaseAuth.currentUser!.uid I get exactly the same Id number as B4Dy...

Comment: Interesting. Are there documents in the `messages` subcollection? And do those document have a `timestamp` field? If so, I recommend next setting a breakpoint on the `if (snapshot.hasError) {` in the `builder` method, running in a debugger, and stepping through the code from there, checking the value of every variable on every line to see if it is what you expect it to be.

Comment: Also, for any of these findings and changes, edit your question (there's a small link right under it) to add the updated code, its output, and other findings. That way others are more likely to see it too.

Comment: You're building your stream in the stream: parameter of StreamBuilder.  Stop that.  See my video https://youtu.be/sqE-J8YJnpg for why

Comment: yes the message collection has some documents, timestamp included.

Comment: I watched your video and tried but I am still running into the same problem. @RandalSchwartz